# How to show second table when other is hidden by JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a searchable table using HTML, CSS and JavaScript - the JavaScript hides the contents of the table, except for the headers and then populates when details are entered into the search bar e.g. 1001, 1002, 1003. However, I'm also now wanting to add a simple separate table on the same page, but the JavaScript seems to hide this table completely as well.

Is there something I can add to the JavaScript to bypass the second table or are there other ways to do this? I'm a complete novice at this, so apologies if things aren't on point as I've had to research a lot of the JavaScript to fit what I was after.

**First table**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.active-row)');

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function ContactsearchFX() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;

  input = document.getElementById("myInput");

  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("compliance-table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }

  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:not(.active-row)');

  if (input.value.length == 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
    
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];

    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: thin solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#compliance-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 25px 0;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  min-width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

#compliance-table th,
#compliance-table td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border-left: thin solid #dddddd;
  border-right: thin solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}

#compliance-table tbody tr {
  border-bottom: thin solid #dddddd;
}

#compliance-table tbody tr.active-row {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #0087AE;
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()" placeholder="Search...">
  
  <table id="compliance-table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="active-row">
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Details</th>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Total No</th>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">w/e 10th Sep</th>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">w/e 17th Sep</th>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">w/e 1st Oct </th>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">w/e 22nd Oct </th>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">w/e 5th Nov</th>
            <th colspan="3" style="background-color: #0087AE; color: white; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">w/e 19th Nov</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="active-row">
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Test 1</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Test 2</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Test 3</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVe</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVc</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">aQIV</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVe</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVc</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">aQIV</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVe</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVc</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">aQIV</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVe</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVc</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">aQIV</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVe</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVc</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">aQIV</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVe</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVc</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">aQIV</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVe</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">QIVc</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">aQIV</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1001</td>
            <td>Test 1001</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>60</td>
            <td>83</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1002</td>
            <td>Test 1002</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>60</td>
            <td>83</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1003</td>
            <td>Test 1003</td>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Second table**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#flu-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%;
  position: fixed;
  
}

#flu-table td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Key</h2>

<table id="flu-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Applicable to</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>QIVe</td>
    <td>Under 65 ONLY</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>QIVc</td>
    <td>Under 65 - <em>can be used for over 65 if aQIV is not available</em></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aQIV</td>
    <td>Over 65 ONLY</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use a more specfic selector for `var rows`

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: `var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#compliance-table tr:not(.active-row)');` ?

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! :D